# For Loop slowing down my app

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

I'm building an app to calculate income, I have a for loop to check whether the income is between 100,000 & 121,200 and if so it decrements the income by 2 and decrements the personalAllowance value by 1 until income reaches 100,000 from the original income value.

It works just fine and outputs the results, however it is stalling my app until the for loop has finished running.

The data is displayed in a table, and there's a text box to enter income. As soon as you enter an income value between 100,000 and 121,000 nothing appears to happen until the for loop has run its course and the values in the table update which is taking a few seconds.

Anyway to fix this? Thanks in advance

```
personalAllowance = 10600;

if (income > 100000 && income < 121200) {
    for (income = income; income > 100000; income -= 2) {
        personalAllowance -= 1;
        NSLog(@"income: %.2f", income);
        NSLog(@"pa: %.2f", personalAllowance);
    }
} else if (income >= 121200) {
    personalAllowance = 0.00;
}
```

FYI: The data in the table is reloaded whenever the value in the textfield is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems easier to just calculate this in one statement, no loop required.

```
if (income > 100000 && income < 121200) {
   int diff = income - 100000;
   personalAllowance -= diff / 2;
   income -= diff;
}
```

Comment: That's great...! been up for hours my head is fried hah thanks for the fresh perspective.